# Simple Mail server setup in LAN (Debian / Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, email, postfix, exim

I want to setup a Mail server in my LAN network, which is 192.168.23.0/255.255.255.0.
The server runs Ubuntu 16.04.2 (amd64) and currently has postfix installed on it. 
The clients are varying... Currently a Debian and a FreeBSD machine. (If this information matters)

**My problem:**

**Information:**

**Domain:** local.net

- Server: Ubuntu (192.168.23.80) | postfix installed (**nuc.local.net**)
- Clients: Mixed, Debian and FreeBSD (192.168.23.100, 192.168.23.101) | exim installed. **This is were i will run the mail command, on both machines**

I want to send mail from my client systems to the Mail server (192.168.23.80), and also from the server to the clients (Mostly from cronjobs).
To be honest... if have no idea what i should do or how i would set this up.. I have never played with SMTP servers so far, at all.
Btw: The server runs BIND9 currently (Name ressolution works fine from the clients)

No matter what i do i always get told by mail (bsd-mailx package) that the "Host or domain name not found. Name service error" on the server (If i try to send a mail to a client system).

I'm sorry if this topic was already discussed here on this very site.. I just did not find anything related to my problem at all.

Again: I only want to deliver locally in my own LAN, nothing more.

Thank you all very much for your help in advance :)

Comment: How did you configure postfix?
Perhaps have a look here: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#local_network

Comment: Please clarify on which host you are trying to run 'mail' command and what domain name you are using for mail.

Comment: the mail server: nuc.local.net (192.168.23.80)  | 
the clients: (this is were i run the mail command): pc.local.net (192.168.23.100) and nb.local.net (192.168.23.100)  the mail command is run on both client machines and also on the mail server (which also runs BIND9).

i hope this clarifies my needs a little more, sorry for not correctly providing the information in the first place.

Comment: @EddieDunn -  I only configured postfix via the debconf hooks which are provided through dpkg-reconfigure postfix on the server... I have never touched the conf files of postfix so far. I have choosen Internet server on the menu and followed the steps.